# excel vba char(10) in for each function

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting error "function not defined" for following code. Can anyone look into this and give me a solution. My thanks in advance!

```
Dim X As String,cell as Range
For Each Cell in Range("A1:A4")
  If(Len(cell.value)>0) Then
  X=X & CHAR(10) & Cell.Value
End If
Next
Range("B1").Value= X

Range("B1").WrapText = True
Range("B1").Columns.AutoFit
```

Here I want to concatenate each non-blank cell into each line in single cell and wrap the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line `X=X & CHAR(10) & Cell.Value` should be  `X=X & CHR(10) & Cell.Value`

Comment: Thank you So much! It worked, I missed on basic...:)